# tcp клиент на python

Tags: python, tcp-ip, клиент

Делаю бота на python, он должен реагировать на сообщения от сервера, то есть примерно такой алгоритм

1. Занимаемся своими делами..
2. Если пришло сообщение обрабатываем..
3. Занимаемся дальше своими делами

Код реализован в виде класса

```
class Spider:
    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        while (1):
             if self.sock.recv(1024):  # Как сделать что бы он не ждал пока придет?
                  #принимаем команду и обрабатываем
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте асинхронные вызовы ([asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html)), либо сделайте-таки несколько потоков и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 5):

Советую почитать про фреймворк [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)